# How to add 3d view in HMS Game Service

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I want to implement the game with 3d view. Is there any plugin for 3d view in HMS game service. If there is any plugin how to add the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for a rendering framework or a game engine because the [Game Service](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-game) only allows you to include services like leaderboards, achievements and save games.

Have a look at the newly released [Computer Graphics Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSCGKit/index.html#0) or [Scene Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSSceneKit/index.html#0). The linked codelabs can be used as a reference to see if that is what you are looking for. The kits themselves let you render 3D models but I would also encourage you to consider using a game engine like [Unity](https://unity.com/) for example. It should be a lot easier to prototype games and you can still include the [HMS Game Service](https://unity.com/).